# How to build a dynamic 2d array inside a constructor?

Tags: c++, arrays, class, multidimensional-array, dynamic-arrays

Building a Memory game. Users can input the number of cards they would like to deal on their 'board'. I am taking that input number(**int size**) and building a 2d array of objects as the game board, which is stored in a constructor. My next step after getting this to work will be to replace the array elements with 'dealt' card objects to display. **Receiving initialization for the arrays and am curious why. Do you have any suggestions as to why or better ways to write this? **

.cpp file relvant code

```
#include <iostream>
#include "GameBoard.h"
#include <math.h> 


using namespace std;

GameBoard::GameBoard(int size)
{

    if (size % 2 != 0)
    {
        size++;
    }

    int row;
    int col;

    row = 4;
    col = ceil(size/4);
    
    Card gameBoard = new Card*[row];

    int i;
    for(i=0; i<row; i++){
        Card gameBoard[i] = new Card[col];
    }
```

.h file

```
#ifndef GameBoard_h
#define GameBoard_h
#include "Deck.h"
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

class GameBoard{
private:
    
     
    Card **gameBoard; 
    Deck deck; 
    Card card;
    int CardsToDeal;
    
    
public:
    GameBoard(int size); 
    GameBoard();
    void initializeBoard();
};

#endif
```

Comment: `Card gameBoard = new Card*[row];` when you add the type at the beginning you are attempting to declare a local `gameBoard` variable instead of initializing the class member.

Comment: @drescherjm Problem Solved. Thank you. I will delete this post now bc a simple error.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the size at compile-time, use `std::array`. When you don't use `std::vector`. These can of course be nested, like:

```
std::array<std::vector<Card>, 4> gameBoard;
```

If the number or "rows" are small you can initialize directly in the constructor initializer list:

```
GameBoard::GameBoard(int size)
    : gameBoard {
          std::vector<Card>(std::ceil(size / 4.0)),
          std::vector<Card>(std::ceil(size / 4.0)),
          std::vector<Card>(std::ceil(size / 4.0)),
          std::vector<Card>(std::ceil(size / 4.0))
      }
{
    // Rest of constructor...
}
```

Otherwise let the array default-construct and set up the vectors inside the constructor body in a loop:

```
GameBoard::GameBoard(int size)
{
    int columns = std::ceil(size / 4.0);
    for (auto& card_vector : gameBoard)
    {
        card_vector.resize(columns);
    }

    // Rest of constructor...
}
```